# ListBox getSelectedIndex; DropDownPanel selections

Tags: gwt, listbox

I simple got a Dialog with a 3 TextBoxes and a ListBox to switch between different input.
Looks like:

```
ListBox dropDownPanel;
TextBox name;
TextBox msg;
Button save, cancel;
```

I call the tuple, Name,msg a profile. so I made changehandler which checks the selected index of the drop down panel ( dropDownPanel.getSelectedIndex(); ) and also a handler which checks if the TextBoxes have changed. If there is any change in the boxes, I created a confirmChangeInfoMessageBox() with 3 possabilities SAVE, DONT SAVE and CANCLE. The first 2 are no problem because both change to the new index. But how can i get back to the privious index if somebody presses cancel ?

Do I always have to save the privious selected value in the form or is there any different way.

thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First thing first :** Cancel issue is **not** as simple as it sounds, specially when dealing with the deep nested objects. We have suffered for months on that.

Well coming to your case, there are two ways:

1) Since its simple you have to keep track of old index and then revert it back if user press Cancel

2) Or redraw the page with proper data fetched from a persistent store.

Or there is a third way of using **Editor Framework** of GWT, well if you can understand that. :P